# How to get worksheet name using Fastexcel in Laravel

Tags: laravel, lumen

I am using FastExcel in Lumen for importing data from excel sheet to database.

```
$collection = (new FastExcel)->withoutHeaders()->import($path);
```

How can I get the worksheet name using FastExcel?

Comment: can you consider upvote and/or accept my answer if it helped you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, there is no way to get the sheet name(names). The PHP library does not support it.

If you want to import a specific sheet, there is no native way to do it. You may try some of the options down below.

1. You know the sheet number.

```php
$collection = (new FastExcel)->withoutHeaders()->sheet(3)->import($path);
```

2. You know the sheet is the first/last sheet.

```php
//last one
$collection = (new FastExcel)->withoutHeaders()->importSheets($path)->last();
// or first one
$collection = (new FastExcel)->withoutHeaders()->importSheets($path)->first();
```

3. If you really want import with a specific name. As far as I know, you have to use another library which is [Box/Spout](https://github.com/box/spout) to help you.

**NOTE: The code below is very old, I am not sure is it still valid for the current version but the logic is correct. You can modify the code to adjust the latest version.**

```php
    use Rap2hpoutre\FastExcel\FastExcel;
    use Box\Spout\Reader\ReaderFactory;
    use Box\Spout\Common\Type;
    
    $sheetNames = [];

    $reader = ReaderFactory::create(Type::XLSX);

    $reader->open($path);

    foreach($reader->getSheetIterator() as $sheet)  {
        if($sheet->getName() == 'TheOneIWant'){
            array_push($sheetNames,$sheet->getName());
        }
    }

    $sheets = (new FastExcel)->importSheets($path);
```

Comment: Yes I want to import a specific sheet

Comment: In addition to @Andy's answer, you can have a look into another library `Laravel-excel`. This library have the facility to get the worksheet names.
https://laravel-excel.com/

Answer (score 0):

We can use withSheetsNames.
Please check reference https://github.com/rap2hpoutre/fast-excel#import-multiple-sheets